# Webpack thinks there are two files whose names differs only in case only

Tags: macos, webpack

For no reason I start to see these messages appearing on the console where I use npm to start my test server:

```
WARNING in ./app/scripts/models/plan.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.

WARNING in ./app/scripts/models/Plan.js
There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Rename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.
```

However if I do a `ls`, there is only one such file in that directory and the name is in capital.

```
ls -l                                                                                                
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 antkong  staff  604 26 Mar 09:44 Plan.js
```

How can I get rid of this message?

I am using osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because I have used the `import Plan from './models/plan';` in one my module.  In osx it will resolve to the `Plan.js`.  However it will be an exception if the code is run on linux or other os with case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: To add to what @Anthony Kong just said -  for those that might encounter the same problem as I did - if your file name is `./my_path/File` one should import it as `import File from './my_path/File'` instead of `import File from './my_path/file'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was I had the following `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        viewline: './Webpack/src/viewline.js',
        dashboard: './Webpack/src/dashboard.js',
        account: './Webpack/src/account.js',
        shiftreport_index: './webpack/src/shiftreport-index.js'
    },
....
```

notice the last record has a lowercase `w` in `./webpack...` where as the others have an uppercase `W`. Making all uppercase solved the problem:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        viewline: './Webpack/src/viewline.js',
        dashboard: './Webpack/src/dashboard.js',
        account: './Webpack/src/account.js',
        shiftreport_index: './Webpack/src/shiftreport-index.js'
    },
...
```

So check your cases everywhere. C